# Suspense in Nextjs makes the api call multiple times

Tags: reactjs, next.js

First clarify that I am new in nextjs and react!

I have this component restaurant.tsx

```
"use client"
import { Suspense, useState, lazy } from 'react'
import { restaurantType } from '@/app/lib/types'

const MenuList = lazy(() => import('@/app/components/MenuList/MenuList'))

export default function Restaurant({restaurant}:{
      restaurant: restaurantType
    }) {
     return (
      <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
       <MenuList restaurantId={restaurant.id} />
      </Suspense>
     )
    }
```

Then MenuList.tsx

```
import { Menu } from '@/app/lib/types'
import { loadMenus } from '@/app/lib/queries'

export default async function MenuList({restaurantId}:{
  restaurantId: number
}) {
  const mMenus:Array<Menu> = await loadMenus({restaurantId})
  return (
    <section id="menus" className='wrapper'> 
      <h4 className='title'>Menu</h4>
      { 
        mMenus.map((menu) =>
          <div key={menu.id}>
            <h5>{menu.attributes.Name}</h5>
            <p>{menu.attributes.Availability}</p>
          </div> 
        )
      }
    </section>
  )
}
```

And finally my query is like this:

```
export async function loadMenus({ restaurantId }:{ restaurantId: number }): Promise<Array<any>> {
  console.log('calls')
  const params = {
    filters: {
      restaurant: {
        id: {
          $eq: restaurantId
        }
      }
    },
    populate: '*',
    fields: ['*'],
    pagination: {},
    publicationState: 'live',
    locale: ['en'],
  }
  const res = await fetch(endpoint('/menus', params), { next: { revalidate: 1 }})
  const data = await res.json()
  return data.data
}
```

So the problem I am having is the query is made more than 15 times.

Is there anything I am missing in order to just wait for the component data to load before showing it?

Comment: There does not seem to be any error here, but you can try setting the `revalidate` option to something in minutes or hours, currently its 1 second.